# Build failed for JSONCPP with Visual C++ 2010

Tags: visual-c++, jsoncpp

I am building JSONCPP on Visual C++ 2010. But it is failing giving the error message:

Unable to start program

'D:\json-cpp-master\makefiles\vs71../../build/vs71/debug/lib_json\lib_json.lib'.

The system cannot find the file specified.

Why is it happening?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem 3 hours ago and figured out that it's named json_vs71_libmt.lib.
Next step is linking it with VS Project.
You'll also need to add

- D:\json-cpp-master\include\ to ProjectProperties->Configuration Properties->VC++ Directories->Include Directories
- D:\json-cpp-master\build\vs71\debug\lib_json\ to ProjectProperties->Configuration Properties->VC++ Directories->Library Directories
- json_vs71_libmt.lib to ProjectProperties->Configuration Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies

After that it works perfect for me.
Hope this'll help.

Comment: It's a better practice to actually describe the solution instead of just linking to another site. Links don't live forever.